# jQuery tap function firing twice on android

Tags: jquery, plugins, tap

I partially modified the `jquery.tapend` plugin to stop it firing tap events on touchmove and some other issues it had. Here is the code:

```
(function($) {
  $.fn.tap = function(fn) {
    return $(this).click.apply(this, arguments) // listen for the final event
                  .bind('touchstart.jqtapstart', function waitForTouchEnd(e) {
      function click(e) {
        cancel(e);
        $(this).trigger('click');
      }
      function move(e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        $this.unbind('.jqtapend');
      }
      function cancel(e) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        if ('object' === typeof e && 'function' === typeof e.preventDefault) {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
        }
        $this.unbind('.jqtapend');
      }
      var timeout = setTimeout(cancel, 250)
        , $this   = $(this) // maybe > 1 node
        ;

      $this.bind({
          'touchend.jqtapend': click,
          'touchmove.jqtapend': move,
          'touchleave.jqtapend': cancel
      });
    });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

For some reason, every single "tap" event on android devices fires twice, and rarely on iOS but it still occurs. Can anyone see why this is happening, or have a theory?

Please note, I chose not to use jquery mobile for certain reasons.

Comment: add [`e.stopImmediatePropagation();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/)

Comment: didn't work, still firing twice